# How to parse string to any F# data?

Tags: f#, f#-data

In F#, any `data` can be `stringify` by function `sprintf` as following:

```
type someKindOfDataType = ...
let data : someKindOfDataType = ...
sprintf "%A" data
```

Can we have a reversal function to parse a string back to `someKindOfDataType`, like following:?

```
let parse<'someKingOfDataType> (s:string) : someKindOfDataType = ....
```

just like JSON.parse in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing what is normally referred to as **serialisation** - converting from an in-memory data structure to a representation that can be transmitted over a network, which could be XML, JSON, binary etc. - and **deserialisation** - the reverse.

`sprintf "%A"` is designed to give a convenient visual representation of data, usually only for the purposes of development as opposed to in production. It does not actually do serialisation, since there is no way to deserialise.

If you want to serialise F# data to a string I would recommend using JSON via library such as [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Note that this will not produce strings that look similar to F# source code like `sprintf "%A"` does because the purpose is different. An example:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject [|Some 3; None|]
// """[{"Case":"Some","Fields":[3]},null]"""

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int option []> """[{"Case":"Some","Fields":[3]},null]"""
// [|Some 3; None|]
```

You need to provide the type to deserialise to and this operation may throw an exception if the string doesn't represent a valid instance of that type.

Comment: Thank you very for your answer.  Your simple example make me know that your answer is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

The standard .NET way is that normally you'll use a `Parse` or `TryParse` method in the class of the type you're trying to parse.

But in F# the `TryParse` function is not very friendly, since it uses an output parameter, still the F# compiler allows you to see it as a tuple, which makes things better but still you'll expect to get an option, here's an example:

```
let a = Int32.Parse "5"
let b = 
    match Int32.TryParse "5" with
    | true, value -> Some value
    | _           -> None
```

If you want to use a library [F#+](https://github.com/gusty/FSharpPlus) has both functions `parse` and `tryParse` which does all the above for you:

```
#r @"FSharpPlus.dll"
open FSharpPlus
open System

let (a:int) = parse "5"
let (b:int option) = tryParse "5"
let (c: Net.IPAddress option) = tryParse "10.0.0.1"

// val a : int = 5
// val b : int option = Some 5
// val c : Net.IPAddress option = Some 10.0.0.1
```

It works as long as the type has either `Parse` or `TryParse` defined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  It is happy to study your library and post.  Your techique to overload the inline function parse in F#+ is interesting and brilliant.  It allows using return type as signature to choose the parser implemented in static parse function in type Parser of converter.fs.  However, as you mention each type much write its only parser function and define in type Parser.  This is not what I.  But thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Not necessarily in type `Parser`, that's true only for types that don't have a "built-in" Parse (or eventually TryParse) method. The examples here do have it already.

Comment: This question of "How to parse a string to a value of a type and stringify a value of a type" leads me to Haskell, which has standard feature of allowing any user defined type deriving Show, Read, so that type will automatically have derived overloaded 'read' and 'print' functions which work just like stringify and parse!  I love Haskell.

Comment: Yes, the same came to my mind when I answered your question ;)